# exponential graphing with intercept

Tags: graphing-functions

[image]

I'm not sure what to do exactly. I got the equation of the line to be $y=\dfrac{p}{\ln\left(p\right)}x+p$ is this correct?

Now I need to solve for x using the above. [image]

Comment: Find $x$ such that $f(x)=0$ and compute $f(0)$. You are searching for the equation $m(y)=f(0)+\frac{f(0)}{-x}y$.

Comment: Yours is obvious not tangent line because $\left. y\right|_{x=0}=p\ne p-1$.

Comment: Please accept one of the answers, if it was helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Find $z$ such that $f(z)=0$:

$$-e^{-z}+p=0 \Leftrightarrow -e^{-z}=-p \Leftrightarrow e^{-z}=p \Leftrightarrow -z = \ln(p) \Leftrightarrow z= -\ln(p).$$

Compute $f(0)$:

$$f(0)=-e^{-0}+p=-1+p=p-1.$$

Your linear equation needs to go through the points

$$
\begin{aligned}
(x_1,y_1)&=(z,0)=(-\ln(p),0)\\
(x_2,y_2)&=(0,f(0))=(0,p-1)
\end{aligned}$$

Therefore your linear equation $y(x)=mx+c$ needs to satisfy

$$
\begin{aligned}
y(z)&= 0\\
y(0)&= p-1
\end{aligned}$$

You find $c$ by calculating

$$
\begin{aligned}
p-1&=y(0)= m\cdot 0 + c = c\\
\end{aligned}$$

After that you can find $m$ by calculating

$$
\begin{aligned}
0=y(z)= m \cdot z + c = m \cdot (-\ln(p)) + p-1
&\Leftrightarrow -(p-1) = m \cdot (-\ln(p))\\
& \Leftrightarrow \frac{p-1}{\ln(p)} = m
\end{aligned}
$$

You end up with

$$c=p-1 \quad \text{and}\quad m=\frac{p-1}{\ln(p)}.$$

You are searching for the equation

$$y(x)=\frac{p-1}{\ln(p)}x+(p-1).$$

Comment: is my equation correct?

Comment: No, you need $p-1$ instead of $p$, because $f(0)=-1+p=p-1$.

Comment: so =ln()+-1?

Comment: now how to solve the equation on the last row?

Comment: =ln()+-1? or  =(p-1)ln()+-1?

Comment: $y=\frac{p-1}{\ln(p)}x+(p-1)$

Answer (score 0):

First, you need to find the $x$-intercept of $f(x)$. To do that, you would need to set the function equal to zero, then solve for $x$. The setup would look like this:

$0=-e^{-x}+p\\
p=e^{-x}\\
\ln(p)=-x\\
x=-\ln(p)$

**x-intercept = $(-\ln(p),0)$**

To get the $y$-intercept, you need to plug in zero for the $x$-value, then solve for $y$. The setup would look like this:

$y=-e^{0}+p\\
y=p-1$

**y-intercept = $(0,p-1)$**

Now that we have the coordinate points of the $x$ and $y$-intercepts, you need to figure out the equation for a straight line that would pass through both of those points. Since you already know what the $y$-intercept should be, all you need is the slope of the line, which is $\frac{\text{rise}}{\text{run}}$:

slope = $\frac{p-1}{\ln(p)}$

**Final equation: $y=\frac{p-1}{\ln(p)}x+(p-1)$**

Comment: is my equaition of the line correct?

Comment: No, it isn't correct. I've updated my answer to show the calculation steps and the correct answer.

Comment: Let me know if your doubt is cleared after this.

Comment: how to solve the equation in the last picture of the OP?

Comment: The answer that I gave you earlier is the exact same as the answer provided later by user408858. I don’t understand why it still isn’t clear, or why you accepted theirs over mine.